# Python Turtle screen not updating

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm new to python and i'm trying to build a snake game but i am not able to understand why the screen is not updating while i call screen.update() so can anybody please help me with that? Thank You!

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import time
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("Snake Game")
segments = []
starting_positions = [(0, 0), (-20, 0), (-40, 0)]
for position in starting_positions:
    new_segment = Turtle(shape="square")
    new_segment.color("white")
    new_segment.penup()
    new_segment.goto(position)
    segments.append(new_segment)
game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    screen.update()
    time.sleep(1)
    for seg in segments:
        seg.forward(20)


screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you never return control to the gui event loop. Instead of using a while loop you should execute your code through callbacks using [`turtle.ontimer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.ontimer) or something similar.

Using this strategy there is no need to ever call `update` because the gui will update itself at the end of every call to the callback function.

For example:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("Snake Game")
segments = []
starting_positions = [(0, 0), (-20, 0), (-40, 0)]
for position in starting_positions:
    new_segment = Turtle(shape="square")
    new_segment.color("white")
    new_segment.penup()
    new_segment.goto(position)
    segments.append(new_segment)
game_is_on = True

def segforward():
    for seg in segments:
        seg.forward(20)
    turtle.ontimer(segforward, 1000)  # 1000 milliseconds

turtle.ontimer(segforward, 1000)   # 1000 milliseconds

screen.exitonclick()
```